# Authlogic and OpenID registration and login in one action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authlogic-oid

I was playing with Rayan Bates http://railscasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic sources as the basis.

So I created few icons for OpenID providers, like Google, Yandex, OpenID, and user have to choose which one to use (similar like here on stackoverflow). So everything is fine. Now I decide to make only one click for login or register: when user click on icon Authlogic have to create new user and authenticate him, or, if user exists, just authenticate him. So I tied to change logic in User#create:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController      
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.save do |result|
      if result
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        @user_session = UserSession.new(:openid_identifier => @user.openid_identifier)
        @user_session.save
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So, if user can't be saved Authlogic will try to authenticate him (of course, user can't be saved not only if there exists another user with same openid_identifier, but just for example). But these scheme isn't work. Nothing happened, `@user_session.save` return nothing in this case.

**Upd**

Looking into *Shripad K* link sources (http://github.com/shripadk/authlogic_openid_selector_example/blob/master/app/models/user_session.rb) I've catch out this:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  auto_register
end
```

`auto_register` is all I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than reinvent the wheel you can give this a try: http://github.com/shripadk/authlogic_openid_selector_example

Live example app: http://testingauth.heroku.com/

Comment: looks interesting. going to look into

Comment: Ok, I've got it: `auto_register` in UserSession model will be enough!

Comment: There is a bug in `auto_register`. In fact i have patched my app with a commit. Look at the latest commit. When you use auto_register without patch it does not return the email address (or any sreg/ax) from the open-id provider!!

Comment: Hey, this looks good I downloaded it to help me with my own problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845463/authlogic-openid-can-create-session-but-not-register) - when I ran the example locally I got: undefined method `authenticate_with_open_id' for #<UserSessionsController:0x46cd5f0> - Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Ehm. As I can't redirect POST to user_sessions create action, so I've made hack like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.save do |result|
      if result
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        if User.find_by_openid_identifier(@user.openid_identifier)
          redirect_to :action => 'login', "user_session[openid_identifier]" => @user.openid_identifier
        else
          render :action => "new"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def login
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    @user_session.save do |result|
      if result
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end    
  end
end
```